# How to select from two or more tables chronologically?

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to select from two big log tables together, and have a chronological result of all the activity.

Let's say I have:

```
Table: MyDb.Building_A
+---------------------+--------------+
| DateTime            | Employee     | (some other columns)
+---------------------+--------------+
| 2019-01-01 08:00:00 | Bob          |
(... millions more rows)

And then another table: MyDb.Building_B
+---------------------+--------------+
| DateTime            | Employee     | (some other columns)
+---------------------+--------------+
| 2019-01-01 08:10:00 | Bob          |
| 2019-01-01 08:20:00 | Peter        |
(... many millions more rows)
```

Now my boss want to see all the access logs across all buildings over a time period (paged data):

I sort of need the data to fit together like a Zipper:

```
+---------------------+--------------+
| 2019-01-01 08:00:00 | Bob          |
| 2019-01-01 08:10:00 | Bob          |
| 2019-01-01 08:20:00 | Peter        |
```

The best I can come up with is to Select individually from both tables into an Array (ORDER BY DateTime), sort the array with both sets of data (using a multidimensional array sort), and then trim the array to a single page worth of data. (I'm getting tired just thinking about this!)

Lots of inefficiency here... Is there a better way?
(Using MySQL)

Comment: i suggest you  giving valid datetime formats in the example data and expected results and not using xxxx or yyyy..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, updated.

Comment: By the way how are the indexes defined?

Comment: @RaymondNijland, the actual data is much more complicated than this - but for the sake of the example, `DateTime` does have an index, and is most often used as the lookup, however the periods are more often set to less then a day because of the volumes.

Comment: By the way can you test using a [view](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/81utGhnRqm9nHDtfKX5d8P/3) on your data like i did here? It seams to be generating a [much better plan](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/81utGhnRqm9nHDtfKX5d8P/4)

Comment: You might when to use `CREATE ALGORITHM=MERGE VIEW Building ..` instead. to forcing getting the [Merging or Materialization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html) optimization for views.

Comment: How? `CREATE VIEW AllBuildings AS ( ... Nick's select from below );`

Comment: "how?" see this [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/81utGhnRqm9nHDtfKX5d8P/3) but you might want to use `CREATE ALGORITHM=MERGE VIEW Building .. ` instead ? for making the view code and how to query the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `UNION` query (in this example, to fetch all accesses this year):

```
(SELECT `DateTime`, Employee 
 FROM MyDb.Building_A
 WHERE `DateTime` BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31')
UNION
(SELECT `DateTime`, Employee 
 FROM MyDb.Building_B
 WHERE `DateTime` BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31')
ORDER BY `DateTime`
```

The `UNION` will get all the rows from each table that meet the `DateTime` criteria, and the `ORDER BY` will sort all the rows by `DateTime`, intermingling building A and B as required.

Note I'm assuming your `DateTime` column is a MySQL `Date` or `DateTime` data type. If it isn't, you may need to use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert it to make the `BETWEEN` logic work.

Comment: Performance wise, what's UNION like? Is the index then based on each table and the overall result filesort?

Comment: @Conrad that would be my expectation, simplest way to be sure is to use `EXPLAIN` on your database.

Comment: @Conrad, Nick is right MySQL optimizer would first execute the first select and the second which can use a index and would merge those results to do the final order by.which might not be able to use a index.. Not sure if MySQL optimizer can materialize (to temporary index the columns) for UNION results.

Comment: @Conrad i did some [testing](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/81utGhnRqm9nHDtfKX5d8P/2).. MySQL  does indeed does not make a auto_key when UNION is used, it will use a temporary and a filesort, which might be (very) bad if a combination "Using temporary Using filesort" is on one record line as MySQL could make a disk based temporary table and sort on disk which is very slow.

Comment: @Nick, i can confirm: `EXPLAIN` is showing 3 rows (something I have not seem before), in the first two it says `Using where; Using index`, and the last row says `Using temporary; Using filesort`. Doing some preliminary test now, seems to return the data as needed.

Comment: @Conrad see mine last comment about "Using temporary; Using filesort" i was predicting it might happen.

Comment: Using the query as it is written, it does use the index for the two select queries but then indeed uses filesort to sort the results. So if the two queries do return a lot of data it could be slow. But I'm not sure what you can do to improve that short of writing the query as a huge `UNION` of `SELECT`s on each individual day in the range.

Comment: Would that filesort then only be sorting through the actual result of the selects, not the entire data set? In reality a page would only be say 100 rows, so then the file-sort would only be done on 200 rows (100 from each set).

Comment: @Conrad yes - the filesort is only applied to the result of the `UNION`. So if that is only 200 rows it should be pretty performant.

Comment: @Nick, How would you implement paging on your solution?

Comment: @Conrad you would have to use a `LIMIT` on the result of the `UNION` as there isn't really any guarantee which table the rows for each page would come from.

Comment: What about [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/81utGhnRqm9nHDtfKX5d8P/4) trick ? @Nick "abusing" the fact MySQL [merges or Materializes views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html)  and using your answer to query the view instead for a much better explain plan by avoiding "Using temporary; Using filesort" combination

Comment: @RaymondNijland but it seems to be using `filesort` on the `VIEW` which will be super slow.

Comment: *"but it seems to be using filesort on the VIEW which will be super slow"* might be i never wrote this kind off "optimization" trick so it's indeed might be a total blunder.

Comment: @RaymondNijland the only way to be sure would be to have some multi-million line tables to play with...